# Set content-length header on script element

Tags: javascript, html, networking, http-headers

I'm having a specific JavaScript file being blocked by my network's firewall and looking at network trace it appears to be due to the server sending "less data than the amount specified in the Content-length header." I'm simply including a file using the src attribute of a script tag in the html document's HEAD. The only caveat is that this is a third party web application so I'm not privy to some of the code generating the pages.

How would one even go about manipulating the content-length header in this scenario?

Comment: Probably it doesn't have to do with content-length. Can you post a minimun, complete and verifiable example?

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does this only happen with a specific script? can you post the URL?

Comment: I'm using "[moment-timezone-with-data.min.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)" served up locally on my site, not from a CDN or anything. And it does appear to only be affecting this script. It is quite large but comparable to something like the jQuery UI library which loads fine in the same exact scenario.